# Searching in specific sheets

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have this macro, and I can't make it perform search only in specific sheets ("aaa","bbb","ccc" in this case).\
 current code returns MsgBox "No purple field found" even if I put it in one of those sheets on purpose.
 I would also my macro to select and show first found cell ( even if currently other sheet is open).
 Please help.

```
Dim cell As Range 
Dim SearchRange As Range 
Dim c As Range 
Dim shtfound As Boolean 
sthfound = False 
On Error Resume Next 
Set SearchRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("bbb", "aaa", "ccc")).UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 
On Error GoTo 0 
If Not SearchRange Is Nothing Then 
    With Application.FindFormat.Interior 
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic 
        .Color = 16711935 
        .TintAndShade = 0 
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0 
    End With 

    Set c = SearchRange.Find(What:="", After:=SearchRange.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _ 
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _ 
    , SearchFormat:=True) 
    If Not c Is Nothing Then 
        firstAddress = c.Address 
        Set foundrange = c 
        Do 
            Set c = SearchRange.Find(What:="", After:=c, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _ 
            xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _ 
            , SearchFormat:=True) 

            Set foundrange = Union(foundrange, c) 
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress 
        foundrange.Activate 
        sthfound = True 
        MsgBox "Purple fields found: " & foundrange.Count 


    End If 
End If 

If sthfound = False Then MsgBox "No purple field found" 
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not loop through the Sheets ? and search each range inside the loop ?

Comment: i suggest the same suggested by Shai Rado

Comment: If you remove the `On Error Resume Next` you will see that you get an error and SearchRange is not set.  Therefore you never go through your `If Not SearchRange Is Nothing Then` block of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply search the entire workbook and then check if it is in the relevant sheet or not. Here is an example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim searchString As String

    '~~> This is your search string
    searchString = "Sid"

    '~~> Loop through the worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set aCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:=searchString, _
                               LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                               LookAt:=xlPart, _
                               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                               SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                               MatchCase:=False, _
                               SearchFormat:=False)

        '~~> If found
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            '~~> Check if it is in the sheet we want
            Select Case aCell.Parent.Name
            Case "aaa", "bbb", "ccc"
                MsgBox "Found in Sheet " & aCell.Parent.Name

                Set bCell = aCell

                '~~> Find other occurances
                Do
                    Set aCell = ws.Cells.FindNext(After:=aCell)

                    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                        If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
                        MsgBox "Found in Sheet " & aCell.Parent.Name
                    Else
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                Loop
            End Select
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Note**: You may want to see [.Find and .FindNext In Excel VBA](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) which explains how `.Find` and `.FindNext` works.

Comment: That is what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot combine ranges from different sheets into one.

The question below is quite relevant and gives a good explanation:
[VBA: How to combine two ranges on different sheets into one, to loop through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25801941/vba-how-to-combine-two-ranges-on-different-sheets-into-one-to-loop-through)

As suggested in the link above, I would cycle through your sheets and append your results at the end.

Comment: the problem is : I have no idea how to make it cycle through Sheets :(