# VBA Excel trying to hide the same columns across multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have exactly the same columns to hide across several workbooks.

Unfortunately, the following code doesn't work well:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim sNames As Variant
sNames = Array("BoM North", "BoM North Extras", "BoM South")
Dim BomColumns As Range
Set BomColumns = Columns("I:J")
For Each sh In sNames
  Sheets(sh).BomColumns.Hidden = True
Next was
```

As I a getting an error:
Object required on the following line:

For each sh in Shnames

The code was picked up from here:

https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-to-hide-columns-on-multiple-sheets.961675/

What object should be assigned here?

UPDATE:

With the following code:

Dim ws As Worksheet
'Dim wsq As Worksheet

Dim BomColumns As Range
Set BomColumns = Columns("I:J")

```
For Each ws In Sheets(Array("BoM North", "BoM North Extras", "BoM South"))
With ws.Range(BomColumns)
.Hidden = True
End With
Next was
```

I have an error:
**Method 'Range of Worksheets' failed**
at the following line:
With ws.Range(BomColumns)

Comment: Try replacing `Sheets(sh).BomColumns.Hidden = True` with `Sheets(sh).range(BomColumns.address).EntireColumn.Hidden = True`. `Set BomColumns = Columns("I:J")` sets a range **in the active sheet**. So you cannot use it in other sheets. But its address, you can... You can do it without preliminarily setting a range: `Sheets(sh).Columns("I:J").Hidden = True`...

Comment: still the same. Should Set BoMColumns = Columns("I:J") go on different place?

Comment: You can set it inside the iteration, but it is useless, anyhow. Try the way I suggested after editing: `Sheets(sh).Columns("I:J").Hidden = True`.

Comment: It doesn't work either

Comment: What "doesn't work" mean? Does it raise an error? If so, what error? If not, what does it do against you want it doing? Are there merge cells involved?

Comment: The error appears exactly in the same line: 424 - Obect required.

Comment: This is different... `sh` must be declared as `Variant` or as `String`. It is not a worksheet... Your code iterates between strings of the array. I did not observe initially where the error is raised.

Comment: This `BomColumns = Columns("I:J")` is actually `BomColumns = ActiveSheet.Columns("I:J")` and does not change in a loop that comes after it. It belongs to a specific sheet, and you cannot use it that way in a loop.

Comment: OK, so what sNames could be then? I set sNames as variant

Comment: I did not say anything about `sNames` variable. `Variant` is OK. Your problem is not there. Setting a range in a sheet (the active one) **cannot be used in other sheets**! Or you set it it during iteration **for every sheet** `Set BomColumns = Sheets(sh).Columns("I:J")` followed by `BomColumns.Hidden = True`, or without this variable, as I suggested above: `Sheets(sh).Columns("I:J").Hidden = True`. And, if you want addressing to me, you need to tag me. Otherwise, I am not notified...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51774011/8422953

Comment: @FaneDuru I've added another approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a minimalistic way of doing it:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

  For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      ws.Columns("I:J").Hidden = True
    Next
```

If it is not all sheets you need, simply replace ThisWorkbook.Worksheets with the range needed