# Method union of object Global failed error

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 worksheets, Inventory Count, Issuance Count and Stock. They look something like this:
[image]
[image]
[image]

So, I am trying to concatenate the Sample numbers in Inventory and Issuance count, and then trying to apply advanced filter to get unique sample numbers in the stock sheet. Here is my code:

```
Sub Stock1()
Dim wbData As Range
Dim wbData2 As Range
Dim unionData As Range
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastrow2 As Long
lastrow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Issuance").Range("B:B")) + 2
lastrow2 = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Inventory").Range("B:B")) + 2
Set wbData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Inventory").Range("B3:B" & lastrow)
Set wbData2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Issuance").Range("B3:B" & lastrow2)

Set unionData = Union(wbData, wbData2)

Set wbExtract = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Stock").Range("B1")

unionData.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CopyToRange:=wbExtract, Unique:=True

'Dim lastrow3 As Long
'lastrow3 = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Stock").Range("B:B"))
```

End Sub

But this is giving me the error in the union line and it says: "Method union of object Global failed error".

Please help, if there is a better other way to achieve the task, I am open to do that as well. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't combine ranges from different sheets into one. However, take a look at this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25801941/vba-how-to-combine-two-ranges-on-different-sheets-into-one-to-loop-through

Comment: I seem to understand the problem now, but I cant seem to be able to use the solution you mentioned to my case

Comment: One: You need a list from which to filter unique sample IDs. Two: You can't do it with Application.Union. Three. Which way do you want to try now? If you don't have a better idea, copy both ranges onto one sheet and filter the result. The problem you present to us isn't one of writing code but one of which target to set for the writing of code.

Comment: So can I create a hidden sheet, copy data from both sheets onto there, and then apply the advanced filter? I need to figure out how to append one data next to another

Comment: Use code like 'WsData.Copy  Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, "A")` Then assign the second range WsData and `With Worksheet("Sheet2"): WsData.Copy Destination:= .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1): End With` and now both ranges are joined in column A of Sheet2 underneath each other.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved my problem