# VBA Excel Union Scope

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using Union to append to a range in a function:

```
Public Function appendRange(col, pRowStart, pRowEnd, rng, sheetObj)

    Dim rngBox01 As range
    Set rngBox01 = rng
    
    Dim rngBox02 As range
    pRng = col & pRowStart & ":" & col & pRowEnd
    Set rngBox02 = sheetObj.range(pRng)
        
    If rngBox01 Is Nothing Then
        Set rngBox01 = rngBox02
    Else
        Set rngBox01 = Union(rngBox01, rngBox02)
    End If
    
    Set appendRange = rngBox01
    
End Function
```

If I use union in this way and set my ranges to be worksheet cells union works fine.
For example:

```
Dim rngBox01 As range
Set rngBox01 = range("A1:A5")
    
Dim rngBox02 As range
Set rngBox02 = range("B1:B5")
    
Set rngBox01 = Union(rngBox01, rngBox02)
```

However, when i try to use parameters i get an application-defined / object-defined error.
I'm confused because the MSDN documentation states that union accepts ranges as parameters.
It also says that the scope is the application.
So, why can I not use function parameters as arguments for union in this case?

Here is main sub:

```
Public Sub getPartDescription()
    
    Dim pnRange As range
    Dim descRange As range
    Dim mfrRange As range
    Dim cstRange As range
    Dim cstExtRange As range
    Dim spaRange As range
    Dim rangeBox As range
       
    Set bomSrc = Workbooks("GVOSS PDP BOMs with Pricing 7-28-2020 RevM.xlsx")
    
    For Each sheet In bomSrc.Sheets
    
        append = setAppendFlag(sheet)
        
        If append Then
        
            ' GET START AND END ROW FOR THE SHEET
            Set rangeBox = sheet.range("E1:E9999")
            pRowStart = getPnColFirstRow(rangeBox)
            pRowEnd = getPnColLastRow(rangeBox)
            Set rangeBox = Nothing
            
            ' APPEND RANGES
            Set pnRange = appendRange("E", pRowStart, pRowEnd, pnRange, sheet)
            Set descRange = appendRange("F", pRowStart, pRowEnd, descRange, sheet)
            Set mfrRange = appendRange("G", pRowStart, pRowEnd, mfrRange, sheet)
            Set cstRange = appendRange("J", pRowStart, pRowEnd, cstRange, sheet)
            Set cstExtRange = appendRange("K", pRowStart, pRowEnd, cstExtRange, sheet)
            Set spaRange = appendRange("L", pRowStart, pRowEnd, spaRange, sheet)
            
            stopHere = True
            
        End If
    Next 'Sheet
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show the line where you actually use `Range` parameters, and also share how you're calling this function?

Comment: you are probably having a worksheet parent issue.  Union cannot be used on ranges in different worksheets.

Comment: Side note... specify your types, e.g. `Public Function appendRange(ByVal col As String, ByVal pRowStart As Long, By Val pRowEnd As Long, ByVal rng As Range, ByVal sheetObj As Worksheet) As Range`.

Comment: Also, your function is defined using `rng` as a variable, and in the function you refer to it as `pRng` - Use `Option Explicit` - or maybe your were trying to use a different variable called `pRng`?

Comment: @braX pRng is just a box for the result of the concatenation: ```pRng = col & pRowStart & ":" & col & pRowEnd```. rng is used at the line ```set rngBox01 = rng```.

Comment: @BigBen I tried declaring my types before posting and it made no difference.

Comment: @ScottCraner, I though about this and I'm wondering why that would be the case if the objects i'm union-ing are instantiations of the range object in the function. Unless they are never actually instantiated and are just pointers back to the workbook. But why would they do that?

Comment: @John - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25801941/vba-how-to-combine-two-ranges-on-different-sheets-into-one-to-loop-through). The ranges *have* to be on the same worksheet.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks for the link; it certainly appears that way. So I guess union looks for something in the range object that ties it to the workbook. I thought that I'd be able to bypass this restriction by instantiating a local object but apparently not. I've since changed the architecture to arrays instead of range objects. I'll just create my own class if i run into issues with the arrays, i guess. Thanks again.

Comment: `Union` returns a `Range` and as a `Range` can only exist in a specific `Worksheet`... by definition you can't have a union of ranges on different worksheets (said in other words I guess).