# Looping through sheets to create conditional list of values from different sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have this problem. Basically, program says it can't use the union range I've created for the .list property of my listbox. I'd like to trigger it when the userform initializes. The problem lies in the last line of code. Although when I try to .select UnionRange it won't work either. But if I do it without looping through the sheets it works ok.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()


Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, RowNo As Long
Dim UnionRange As Range


'Loops through all sheets in workbook

For Each sh In Worksheets
    
    'Stops looping when it reaches "LISTS" sheet
    
    If sh.Name = "LISTS" Then
        Exit For
    End If
    
    sh.Activate
    
    RowNo = Range("e6").End(xlDown).Row
    
    For i = RowNo To 1 Step -1
        If Range("K" & i) = "TBD" Then
            If UnionRange Is Nothing Then
                Set UnionRange = Range("k" & i)
            Else
                Set UnionRange = Union(UnionRange, Range("k" & i))
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
Next

'Error is next, should populate listbox list

lbTBDNAV.List = UnionRange.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA: How to combine two ranges on different sheets into one, to loop through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25801941/vba-how-to-combine-two-ranges-on-different-sheets-into-one-to-loop-through)

Comment: It makes no sense to combine all cells that are equal to `TBD`. Did you want to combine cells in another column or is TBD part of the strings? Maybe you want to look in `E` and use `K`. Please clarify. BTW, you cannot combine ranges from different worksheets. You are calculating the last row from `E6` yet you are looping until row `1`. Instead of activating the worksheet, qualify the ranges with `sh.Range(...)`.