# VBA Excel defining value of cells for multiple worksheets at once

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to provide the values for several cells in a few worksheets at once and wondering how it could be possible.

I found a nice workaround here:

[VBA: How to combine two ranges on different sheets into one, to loop through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25801941/vba-how-to-combine-two-ranges-on-different-sheets-into-one-to-loop-through)

but the  major problem is,  that with  this solution I can do it only for one cell.

I tried to make this code for more than one cell, but I've failed.

```
   Dim Floors(5) As Range, FNo As Integer
   Dim SampleCell As Range, SampleTarget As Range
   Dim SampleCell2 As Range, SampleTarget2 As Range

   Set Floors(0) = Worksheets("Ground Floor Plan")
   Set Floors(1) = Worksheets("First Floor Plan")
   Set Floors(2) = Worksheets("Second Floor Plan")
   Set Floors(3) = Worksheets("Third Floor Plan")
   Set Floors(4) = Worksheets("Fourth Floor Plan")
   Set Floors(5) = Worksheets("Fifth Floor Plan")
   Set SampleCell = .Range("M5")
   Set SampleCell2 = .Range("M25")

   For FNo = 0 To 5
   
   For Each SampleCell In Floors(FNo)
   SampleCell = "Cocolocco lusis ponton"
   SampleTarget(SampleCell.Row, SampleCell.Column) = SampleCell

    Next SampleCell
    For Each SampleCell2 In Floors(FNo)
    SampleCell2 = "Other SampleCell Value"
    SampleTarget2(SampleCell2.Row, SampleCell2.Column) = SampleCell2
   Next FNo
```

The code seem to work, but nothing is placed in the range. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the edited code:

```
Sub floorssub()
Dim floors(5) As Worksheet, FNo As Integer
   Dim SampleCell As Range, SampleTarget As Range
   Dim SampleCell2 As Range, SampleTarget2 As Range

   Set floors(0) = Worksheets("Ground Floor Plan")
   Set floors(1) = Worksheets("First Floor Plan")
   Set floors(2) = Worksheets("Second Floor Plan")
   Set floors(3) = Worksheets("Third Floor Plan")
   Set floors(4) = Worksheets("Fourth Floor Plan")
   Set floors(5) = Worksheets("Fifth Floor Plan")

   For FNo = 0 To 5
   Set SampleCell = floors(FNo).Range("M5")
    SampleCell = "Cocolocco lusis ponton"
   Set SampleTarget = floors(FNo).Cells(SampleCell.Row, SampleCell.Column) 
   SampleTarget = SampleCell


    Set SampleCell2 = floors(FNo).Range("M25")
    SampleCell2 = "Other SampleCell Value"
    Set SampleTarget2 = floors(FNo).Cells(SampleCell2.Row, SampleCell2.Column)
    SampleTarget2 = SampleCell2
   Next FNo
 End Sub
```

SIDENOTE: This is only for demo how to use objects and assign values to them.

Answer (score 2):

### Populate the Same Cells in Multiple Worksheets

```vb
' Writes each value ('CellValues')
' to each corresponding cell ('CellAddresses')
' on each worksheet ('SheetNames')
' of the workbook containing this code ('ThisWorkbook').

Sub PopulateCellsMulti()

    Dim CellValues() As Variant: CellValues = VBA.Array( _
        "Cocolocco lusis ponton", "Other SampleCell Value")
    Dim CellAddresses() As Variant: CellAddresses = VBA.Array( _
        "M5", "M25")
    
    Dim SheetNames() As Variant: SheetNames = Array( _
        "Ground Floor Plan", "First Floor Plan", "Second Floor Plan", _
        "Third Floor Plan", "Fourth Floor Plan", "Fifth Floor Plan")

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim ws As Worksheet, SheetName As Variant, n As Long
    
    For Each SheetName In SheetNames
        Set ws = wb.Sheets(SheetName)
        For n = 0 To UBound(CellValues)
            ws.Range(CellAddresses(n)).Value = CellValues(n)
        Next n
    Next SheetName
   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version without loop on the sheets:

```
Sub PopulateCellsMulti_x()

    Dim CellValues() As Variant: CellValues = VBA.Array( _
        "Cocolocco lusis ponton", "Other SampleCell Value")
    Dim CellAddresses() As Variant: CellAddresses = VBA.Array( _
        "M5", "M25")
    
    Dim SheetNames() As Variant: SheetNames = Array( _
        "Ground Floor Plan", "First Floor Plan", "Second Floor Plan", _
        "Third Floor Plan", "Fourth Floor Plan", "Fifth Floor Plan")

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim n As Long
    
    ' without loop on the sheets
    
    wb.Sheets(SheetNames).Select
    For n = 0 To UBound(CellValues)
        Range(CellAddresses(n)).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = CellValues(n)
    Next n
    Sheets(1).Select
End Sub
```